# linear mixed model: 2 fixed effects in a crossed(?) design? lmer

Tags: r, categorical-data, lme4-nlme, effects

We have a continuous variable intensity as a dependent variable.
Three categorical variables: material(A,B,C,D), group(1,2,3,4,5,6,...), patient_id.
patient_id is supposed to be a random effect.

We would like to know how the different categories of material influence the dependent variable in different categories of groups.
intensity of A1 compared to B1 C1 D1
intensity of A2 compared to B2 C2 D2
...

Using r, i tried:

```
lmer(intensity~  material*group + (1|patient_ID), data)
```

However this leads to:
A1 as reference and modeling of
intensity of A1 compared to B1 C1 D1
intensity of A1 compared to B2 C2 D2
...

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: For some reason your DV doesn't sound normally distributed. Is it a likert scale test?

Comment: my DV is fluorescence intensity. it is normally distributed

Comment: Okay. What does your regression summary show? Paste it into your question if you can. The way your question is worded isn't clearly conveying to me what the issue is exactly, but I could be reading it wrong.

Comment: I was under the (wrong) impression that the model would only use A1 as the reference for all "comparisons". However, I was now able to resolve this problem as indeed the function, as written above reflects exactly my research question.